# Show that $\#(Y^X) = \#(Y)^{\#(X)}$.

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

(Proposition 3.6.14 in Analysis 1 by Tao) Let $X$ and $Y$ be finite sets. Then the set $Y^X$ is finite and $\#(Y^X) = \#(Y)^{\#(X)}$. $\#$ denotes the cardinality of a set and $Y^X = \{f |f:X \to Y\}$ (a collection of all functions from $X$ to $Y$).

Attempt: Let $\# (Y) = m$ and $ \#(X) = n$. I argue that $\# (Y^X) = m^n$ and prove this by induction on the cardinality of $X$. Consider the base case, $k=1$. Then, there are $m$ functions from $X$ to $Y$ ($f_1(x) = y_1, ... , f_m(x) = y_m$ for $x \in X$ and $y_i \in Y$). We assume that the argument is true for $k=n$. Consider the case, $k= n+1$.

I am stuck here, and any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

By the inductive assumption we have $m^n$ functions from $\{x_1,\dots,x_n\}$ to $\{y_1,\dots,y_m\}$. To define a function  $f:\{x_1,\dots,x_n,x_{n+1}\}\to\{y_1,\dots,y_m\}$, all we need to do is pick where to send $x_{n+1}$. There are $m$ options, so we have $m\times m^n = m^{n+1}$ and we're done.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I also thought in the same way, but why do we multiply $m$ instead of adding $m$?

Comment: For every function $f_n:\{x_1,\dots,x_n\}\to\{y_1,\dots,y_m\}$, we have $m$ different functions that extend $f_n$ by defining the image of $x_{n+1}$.

Comment: I feel that this argument relies too much on one's everyday intuition of multiplication, and might therefore not be considered rigorous enough (i.e. one should instead try to derive it purely through set-algebraic identities).